# vars_files: doesn't work. Not able to parse/read variables

Tags: ansible-inventory

```yaml
hosts:
  vars_files:
    - utv_vars.yml
```

Get this in run:

> [WARNING]: Skipping key (vars_files) in group (hosts) as it is not a mapping, it is a <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

Comment: `vars_files` should not be nested under `hosts`, but should be at the same level. Have a look at the examples in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-included-files-and-roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
added dir /group_vars/utv_vars.yml